# GitHub: create a branch off an older version of main branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, version, branch

I currently work for a company that has a **main** branch, **dev**elopment branch, and individual task branches (see link)
[Our Branches Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPoFc.jpg).
Changes were recently made to the **main** branch which caused a series of broken functions, which came from a push from **dev** branch. Some parts of our **main** branch works better than the old one though.

Because both team branches aren't fully functional, is there a way to create a branch off of an older version of **main**?
Also, where can I view older versions of a branch in GitHub?

We could technically restore an old version of **main** and make a branch, but that would destroy some good code that has been pushed recently.

Comment: Branches are simply pointers to a commit. When you create a new branch you can specify whatever commit you'd like. Look at the history of `main`, pick the commit ID you wish to create the branch from, and then `git branch new-branch-name <commit-ID>` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, where can I view older versions of a branch in GitHub?

Viewing older versions of a branch is all about exploring the commit history.

Commands you need:

1. `git branch [New_Name] [Commit_Hash]` - Create a new branch based on a specific point in history.
2. `git cherry-pick [Commit_Hash]` - Apply changes from a specific commit (from a different branch) to the current branch. [git-cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

One for to go back, and the other one to pick the good commits that you want to keep.

---

A simplified scenario to explain the overall process:

1. `git switch main`.
2. `git log --oneline` - To see the commit history of the main branch.

   ```
   4888ee1 (HEAD -> main) Merge branch 'dev'
   1a2ae1c (dev) 3rd commit (dev)
   827bd7e 2nd commit (dev)
   940b5cf 1st commit (dev)
   3d7367c 2nd commit (main)
   90aef92 1st commit (main)
   ```
3. We want to go the "2nd commit (main)" state of the main branch. So, `git branch main_fix 3d7367c`.
4. `git switch main_fix` and then `git log --oneline`:

   ```
   3d7367c 2nd commit (main)
   90aef92 1st commit (main)
   ```
5. > Some parts of our main branch works better than the old one

   Lets say "2nd commit (dev)" was the good one. So, `git cherry-pick 827bd7e`, then resolve conflicts (pick what you want to keep), and `git add .` and finally `git cherry-pick --continue`.
6. `git log --oneline`:

   ```
   5187548 (HEAD -> main_fix) 2nd commit (dev)
   3d7367c 2nd commit (main)
   90aef92 1st commit (main)
   ```

Extra: Sometimes, the official docs can be too confusing. Here is [a simplified version of Git](https://github.com/shaanaliyev/tech-stack/blob/main/git/README.md) if you want.